# Why is my application always connecting to 'public' schema?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

I am trying to connect to postgres database using springboot+jpa

The postgres has two schemas in the database

```
public
ratings
```

The ratings schema has the tables food_ratings

The default schema is always picked up as public and not as ratings schema even though I tried the following approaches that were widely suggested

->Setting up the default schema explicitly in the application properties

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=ratings
```

->Setting the schema as ratings explicitly in the entity

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "food_ratings", schema = "ratings")
public class FoodRatings implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;

   @Column(name="description")
    String description;

}
```

I end up getting error as

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "food_ratings" does not exist
```

Note: I am using all lower case in both the code and the db for the schema name and table name.
What other option am I missing here?

Comment: in properties .. try this : spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/db_name?currentSchema=schema_name

Comment: it did not work. will it it in description

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the postgres driver version. I was using 9.x version.

Upgrading it to 42.0.0 made it work.